# Chart not getting displayed in Email body of outlook trigger by logic app

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have followed instructions in below link and was able to successfully send the Email from Logic app. but appinsights query which is selected as TimeChart is not getting displayed in email body instead some junk characters are displayed, same TimeChart is displayed in attachment with out any issues.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/automate-with-logic-apps

Appreciate if any one can help

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the same with couple of modifications. The code view of send email action looks like :

[image]

Also, I did not add the extra parameters : "Is HTML" and "Attachments". Actions look like :

App Insight action:

[image]

Send email :

[image]

Email received :

[image]

Comment: Hi Jaya, thanks for your inputs.  HTML table works fine, only issue occurs when we try to display a chart(TimeChart or pieChart). It displays some junk characters in the email body